# Mysql: Is it possible to use a subquery inside a from clause in order to pick the table name from another table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I was wondering if there's any way to add a subquery with a switch case to the form clause of my select query in order to select a table based on a condition.

For example:

```
select a.* 
from (select (case when (table2.column = 'something')
                   then (table2.tablename1)
                    else (table2.tablename2)) as tablename
      from table2
      where table2.column2 = 'blabla'
      limit 1
     ) a
```

I tried to write that in many variation & so far non of them worked.
On the most successful tryouts (when I got no mysql errors) it returned the name of the table as the result itself (for example: the value that's in table2.tablename2). I understand why it did that (because I selected everything from a select results...) but how can I use the tablename from the results in order to set the table on the main query?
Hope that make sense...
Any idea?

Comment: Can you include some sample data here?  It may be possible to do what you have in mind via this or some other route.

Comment: Regarding the subquery, that's pretty much what I need, but with different names. What did you mean by sample data?

Comment: Show sample input and output.  As I mentioned, there may be a workaround which doesn't involve what you have in mind.